# Instrument automation with BDD/TDD on Python

Tags: python, automation, instruments

I was wondering if it would be possible to use instrument automation tests in behave driven (or test driven) development codes?

I mean the code tested would communicate with instruments that uses PyVISA and TCP/IP communication to send commands and acquire data.

Best,

Comment: You can achieve that by using https://github.com/behave/behave

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is this a modified version of behave? Does it really allow usage of PyVISA and TCP/IP in the tests?

Comment: As far as I remember, you can describe some functionality with Python and then call them through the BDD tests. So, if you describe PyVISA or TCP/IP, so I believe you can call them.